# Referencing LaTeX package used to create figures in a paper

Tags: tikzpeople

I used the `tikzpeople` package to create some figures for a journal paper that will be licensed with CC BY when published.

I'm wondering if the package needs to be referenced when used to create figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tikzpeople is released under the [LPPL](https://www.latex-project.org/lppl/lppl-1-3c/) which places no restrictions on how its output may be used, so you should be fine.

Comment: But take into account what the documentation of tikzpeople say: "Let me start with a word of warning: The node-shapes defined by this package are heavily influenced by a type of clip art included in the Microsoft Visio software. I am by no means an expert on copyright law and as such can make no claim under which circumstances using these shapes might infringe on Microsoft's copyright.I do not expect that there are any problems, but be aware of this. Let's consider this package an homage to the great design of those Visio clip arts and get on with our lives."

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but the tikzpeople shapes are sufficiently different from the visio clipart shapes that it would be difficult to imagine any case could be made for any ip infringement. As near as I can tell, incidentally, there is no case law about what happens if the provider of clipart infringes on someone else's copyright and how that would impact users of that clipart.

Comment: If you want to reference them, knock yourself out.  I've seen credit given to typewriters and parents DNA.